# get only symbols and companies' names from nasdaq

Tags: finance

I can get information from nasdaq with this request
http://www.nasdaq.com/screening/companies-by-name.aspx?letter=0&exchange=nasdaq&render=download
and the result will have this columns
`Symbol,Name,LastSale,MarketCap,ADR TSO,IPOyear,Sector,industry,Summary Quote`

but in my database I've got table with columns - `Symbol`and `Name`. 
Is it possible to get only symbols and names from request(because then I can easy read all data from .csv result to database)?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to contact NASDAQ regarding their API and see if they accept parameters to modify this CSV output.  They might have more documentation for it somewhere on their website.

An alternative would be to download the data and parse it to get only what you need. To help with this you'll need to provide more data regarding programming language and such.

Comment: I can parse it myself(C#) but I need to parse it and take first 2 elements of each line of csv and then write result to database. but it much more longer way

Comment: What database server are you using?  If you're using MSSQL, you could make a SSIS package quickly and schedule it as a job.